# Convert Canvas to image and send by email using sp-send-dbmail

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, html5-canvas, sp-send-dbmail

Currently I am trying to send an email using a stored procedure in SQL Server (extracting and showing data from some queries) by trying to convert an HTML Canvas into a PNG image and send it on the mail's body (no attachments). However all I get is a blank email.

The idea is to generate an image with the whole data for every row and send it to the corresponding email.

Here is the canvas from the rectangles I want to make but to no avail.

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <title>Image</title>
   <script>

function init() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

         ctx.fillRect(50,50,50,50);

          var img = new Image();
          img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
          return img;
}

function draw(ctx) {

  var alpha = ctx.globalAlpha;

  // capa1/Rectngulo
  ctx.save();
  ctx.save();
  ctx.shadowColor = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0.0;
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = 7.0;
  ctx.shadowBlur = 10.0;
  ctx.globalAlpha = alpha * 0.30;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(294.4, 146.3);
  ctx.lineTo(15.9, 146.3);
  ctx.lineTo(15.9, 8.0);
  ctx.lineTo(294.4, 8.0);
  ctx.lineTo(294.4, 146.3);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(213, 213, 213)";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.lineWidth = 0.8;
  ctx.stroke();

  // capa1/Rectngulo
  ctx.shadowColor = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0.0;
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = 7.0;
  ctx.shadowBlur = 10.0;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(294.4, 338.2);
  ctx.lineTo(15.9, 338.2);
  ctx.lineTo(15.9, 199.8);
  ctx.lineTo(294.4, 199.8);
  ctx.lineTo(294.4, 338.2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();

  // capa1/Rectngulo
  ctx.shadowColor = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0.0;
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = 7.0;
  ctx.shadowBlur = 10.0;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(613.3, 241.4);
  ctx.lineTo(334.8, 241.4);
  ctx.lineTo(334.8, 103.1);
  ctx.lineTo(613.3, 103.1);
  ctx.lineTo(613.3, 241.4);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();

  // capa1/Rectngulo
  ctx.shadowColor = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0.0;
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = 7.0;
  ctx.shadowBlur = 10.0;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(932.8, 148.2);
  ctx.lineTo(653.8, 148.2);
  ctx.lineTo(653.8, 35.9);
  ctx.lineTo(932.8, 35.9);
  ctx.lineTo(932.8, 148.2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();

  // capa1/Rectngulo
  ctx.shadowColor = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0.0;
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = 7.0;
  ctx.shadowBlur = 10.0;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(932.8, 308.2);
  ctx.lineTo(653.8, 308.2);
  ctx.lineTo(653.8, 195.9);
  ctx.lineTo(932.8, 195.9);
  ctx.lineTo(932.8, 308.2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1315" height="361"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

The code in the SQL Server stored procedure for the HTML part is like this:

```
 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
   @profile_name = 'SQL ALERTING',  
   @body = @body,
   @body_format ='HTML',
   @recipients = @@email,
   @subject = 'Test' ;
```

Can anyone help me in telling me what is wrong or if there is an alternative? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should assume that Javascript functionality is not available in any modern mail clients.

Comment: In addition to AlwaysLearnings comment, the (correct) alternative, is to send your email from an application which is designed to do it. SQL Server is not the right place to send emails from and has only very poor tools.